# Setting Swing combobox tiptool to selected item

Tags: java, swing, combobox, mouseover

I have a combobox in which the items are Objects, the string value of which can be lengthy. Rather than making the box longer I'd like the full text to appear with mouse float over. How can I do that?

Comment: Have a look at [How to Use Combo Boxes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) and [Providing a Custom Renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer).  The custom renderer allows you to apply a tooltip to the component which should then be displayed (assuming non has been applied directly to the combobox)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of this by using a [custom cell renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer).

As it's written, you can use my example by saying the following:

```
ToolTipRenderer.addRenderer(jComboBox, foo -> foo.getTheLongString());
```

(Or you can copy and refactor it if you don't want the generic/Java 8 stuff.)

I'm basically using a decorator pattern here, instead of doing something like extending `DefaultListCellRenderer`. This way if the `JComboBox` is already using something different the behavior is kept. All you really care about to set a tool tip is whether the component is some subclass of `JComponent`.

```
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.function.Function;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.Component;

public class ToolTipRenderer<E> implements ListCellRenderer<E> {
    private final ListCellRenderer<? super E> delegate;
    private final Function<E, String> toStringFn;

    public ToolTipRenderer(ListCellRenderer delegate,
                           Function<E, String> toStringFn) {
        this.delegate   = Objects.requireNonNull(delegate);
        this.toStringFn = Objects.requireNonNull(toStringFn);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends E> list,
                                                  E value,
                                                  int index,
                                                  boolean isSelected,
                                                  boolean cellHasFocus) {
        Component result =
            delegate.getListCellRendererComponent(
                list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

        if (result instanceof JComponent) {
            // if you don't want to use generics,
            // replace this with
            //            = value.getTheLongString();
            String ttText = toStringFn.apply(value);
            ((JComponent) result).setToolTipText(ttText);
            // I was not sure if you wanted
            // something like this too.
            // if (result instanceof JLabel) {
            //     ((JLabel) result).setText(value.getTheShortString());
            // }
        }

        return result;
    }

    // This is an example of how it should be used.
    // Pass the ToolTipRenderer the previous renderer
    // from comboBox.getRenderer().
    public static <E> void addRenderer(JComboBox<E> comboBox,
                                       Function<E, String> toStringFn) {
        ListCellRenderer<? super E> delegate = comboBox.getRenderer();
        comboBox.setRenderer(new ToolTipRenderer<E>(delegate, toStringFn));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic solution is to provide a `ListCellRenderer` which sets the returned `Component`s `toolTipText` property to the appropriate value you need

`DefaultListCellRenderer` extends from `JLabel`, so you can simply use it's `toolTipText` method to supply what ever "extended" text you want, for example.

```
public class ToolTipListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        // I'd extract the basic "text" representation of the value
        // and pass that to the super call, which will apply it to the 
        // JLabel via the setText method, otherwise it will use the
        // objects toString method to generate a representation
        super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus); 
        setToolTipText("To what ever you need based on the value that has been passsed");
        return this;
    }

}
```

See [How to use comboboxes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) and [Providing a custom renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer) for more details