# Grid selection popup for combo box

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a `JComboBox` that lets you select a profile image - a gallery of sorts.

An image of my current combo box:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgfGr.png]

You can already see how unwieldy this would be, should I add more images.

Essentially, I would like to "replace" the popup with a grid-based one, to allow for easier selection of an image.
I would like to keep the appearance of the combo box itself, however - showing details about the currently selected image.

The only way I can currently see to do this is to use a custom Look and Feel UI class, which AFAIK would make the combo box look out-of-place due to the rest of my app using the system L&F.

Comment: Maybe this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43621987/setting-swing-combobox-tiptool-to-selected-item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The popup of the combo box uses a `JList` to display the items.

You can configure the `JList` to use horizontal wrapping:

```
BasicComboPopup popup = (BasicComboPopup)comboBox.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleChild(0);
JScrollPane scrollPane = (JScrollPane)popup.getComponent(0);
JList list = (JList) scrollPane.getViewport().getView();
list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.HORIZONTAL_WRAP);
list.setVisibleRowCount(2);
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Initializing a List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#init) for more information.

Comment: This works, but it's not exactly pretty since it's still displaying both the icon and the text associated with the entry: [image example](https://i.imgur.com/eCWIZxn.png)
Is there a way around this?

Comment: Oh, right, it's a `JList` - I can just give it its own cell renderer!